# How to get the exact json node instance using groovy?

Tags: json, groovy, types

Input
Json file :

```
{
   "menu": {
     "id": "file",
     "value": "File",
     "popup": {
          "menuitem": [
               {
                   "value": "New", 
                   "onclick": ["CreateNewDoc()","hai"],
                   "newnode":"added"
               }
          ]
      }
  }
}
```

Groovy code :

```
def newjson = new JsonSlurper().parse(new File ('/tmp/test.json'))
def value=newjson.menu.popup.menuitem.value
def oneclick=newjson.menu.popup.menuitem.onclick
println value
println value.class
println oneclick
println oneclick.class
```

Output:

```
[New]
class java.util.ArrayList
[[CreateNewDoc(), hai]]
class java.util.ArrayList
```

Here,
 
The json nodes which carries String and List returns the same class name with the groovy code above shown.

- How can i differentiate that nodes `value` and `oneclick`. Logically I expect `value` should be a `instance of String`. but both returns as `ArrayList`.
- How to get the exact type of node in json using groovy.

Update 1:

I don't exactly know, can do this like shown below. My expectation to get the results this,

```
New
class java.util.String
[CreateNewDoc(), hai]
class java.util.ArrayList
```

Comment: It is just a String and a List.  JSON can only deal with those basic types (and object, bool, nil, ...)

Comment: @cfrick Can i get those answers like shown above in Update 1

Comment: You are fetching values from lists. You have to decide, if you need all or just the first or the last etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

- In the below script using closure to show the details of each value and its type
- Another closure is used to show the each map in the `menuitem` list.

```groovy
def printDetails = { key, value -> println "Key - $key, its value is \"${value}\" and is of typpe ${value.class}" }

def showMap = { map -> map.collect { k, v -> printDetails (k,v) } }

def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(new File('/tmp/test.json'))
def mItem = json.menu.popup.menuitem
if (mItem instanceof List) {
   mItem.collect { showMap it  }
}
println 'done'
```

You can quickly try the same online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/KxHGKs)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

**menuitem** is list, so you need to get property on concrete list element:

```
assert newjson.menu.popup.menuitem instanceof List
assert newjson.menu.popup.menuitem[0].value instanceof String
assert newjson.menu.popup.menuitem[0].onclick instanceof List
```

Answer (score 1):

in your json the `menuitem` contains array of one object:

```
      "menuitem": [
           {
               "value": "New", 
               "onclick": ["CreateNewDoc()","hai"],
               "newnode":"added"
           }
      ]
```

and when you try to access `menuitem.value` groovy actually returns a list of `value` attributes for all objects in `menuitem` array.

that's why `menuitem.value` returns array `["New"]`

in this case

```
      "menuitem": [
           {
               "value": "New", 
               "onclick": ["CreateNewDoc()","hai"],
               "newnode":"added"
           },
           {
               "value": "Old", 
               "onclick": ["CreateOldDoc()","hai"],
               "newnode":"added"
           }
      ]
```

`menuitem.value` will return array `["New", "Old"]`

but `menuitem[0].value` will return the string value `"New"`

so in your groovy code to get attributes of first menu item:

```
def value=newjson.menu.popup.menuitem[0].value
def oneclick=newjson.menu.popup.menuitem[0].onclick
```